# Make Array of Objects from json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have this object

```
stdClass Object (
  [reportDate] => 2014-02-02
  [shops] => Array (
    [24] => stdClass Object (
      [shopid] => 24
      [cashiers] => Array (
        [1] => stdClass Object (
          [cashierid] => 1
          [products] => Array (
            [moneyIn] => 46
            [moneyOut] => 215.14
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

And When i make json_encode on it I get this json string

```
   {
      "reportDate":"2014-02-02",
      "shops":{
        "24":{
          "shopid":24,
          "cashiers":{
            "1":{
              "cashierid":1,
              "products":{
                "moneyIn":"46",
                "moneyOut":"215.14"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This result is not what I wanted. I want array of objects.

So instead of this "`shops":{` I want this `"shops":[`
Instead of this `"cashiers":{` I want this `"cashiers":[` And so on.

Where ever there is an array in my stdClass I want array and where there is stdClass I want object.

So what am I doing wrong in structuring my initial stdClass Object.

Answer (score 1):

An associative array results in an object, as you've seen. To produce a JSON array you need an array composed of arrays.

Here's an example

```
$shops  = [['shopid'=>24, 'cashiers'=>[['cashierId'=>1]]]];
```

Produces

```
[
   {
      "shopid":24,
      "cashiers":[{"cashierId":1}]
   }
]
```

And here's the [live runnable demo](http://phpepl.cloudcontrolled.com?code=%24shops%20%20%3D%20%5B%5B'shopid'%3D%3E24%2C%20'cashiers'%3D%3E%5B%5B'cashierId'%3D%3E1%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%0A%0Aecho%20json_encode(%24shops)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have associative arrays in JSON. An associative array will always become an object in JSON after json_encode.